# PHP disabling SHM cache

Tags: php, caching, server

I am struggling with my new server configuration after migration and I am looking for an advice on how to disable SHM cache in .htaccess file. After disabling OPcache I am still getting

Opcode Caching  Disabled
Optimization    Disabled
SHM Cache   **Enabled**
File Cache  Disabled

I suppose it is responsible for weird behaviour like not refreshing the page until I wait 3 seconds or paste random GET params in url which is a very inelegant solution. I also noticed even worse things like completely ignoring server session and using others' user variables. I don't know how it works, but I can say my websites were fine before the migration on a server that was weaker but more reliable. Any ideas how to solve these issues? Hosting support seems to completely ignore the issue and assume I broke something in the code, but that isn't the case.

Comment: As it has no php.ini configuration parameters, so I would say, you can't.

Comment: @MarkusZeller Any ideas what could be the actual cause of session issues and non-refreshing pages?

Comment: What PHP-version are you using? Which system and Apache version?

Comment: Maybe something went wrong during the PHP installation. A reinstall could help. But, when your hoster support can not help, I suppose, there is nothing you can do by yourself.

Comment: Another Question: Are you sure this is not a local problem? Did you try on another device to be certain it is no local caching.

Comment: @MarkusZeller I am sure it's the server that's wrong here, tried on different devices and have been notified from many people about glitches a few times. On the previous server it worked all fine except we had to move because of bad performance - which was probably because of heavy wordpress site on the same server.

Comment: Maybe you have some caching issues on that Wordpress due to (caching) plugins. Did you try to test a simple PHP file for confirmation?

Comment: @MarkusZeller I have built 2 raw php websites on that server (currently working on 3rd) and these issues are referring to them. The wordpress just exists on that server and consumes enormous amounts of resources so I have to keep my projects lightweight not to destroy it. And as u can see nothing makes sense. The only thing that changed was the server itself and it was when I noticed these glitches. I could just find another one and pay for it but I dont get it how can it not work as expected.